# Grails: testing a redirect with an integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I'm using Grails 1.3.7.  I'm trying to test a redirect in my integration test.  Here is my controller and method in question ...

```
class HomeController {

def design = {
    ....
            if (params.page) {
                redirect(uri: "/#/design/${params.page}")
            }
            else {
                redirect(uri: "/#/design")
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

However in my integration test, the call to "controller.response.redirectedUrl" is failing (always returns null) even though I know the redirect call is being made (verified through logging).  What is wrong with the integration test below?

```
class HomeControllerTests extends grails.test.ControllerUnitTestCase {
    ....

    void testHomePageDesign() { 
       def controller = new HomeController()

       // Call action without any parameters
       controller.design()

       assert controller.response.redirectedUrl != null

       assertTrue( responseStr != "" )
    }
```

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

Changing your **HomeControllerTests** to extend **GrailsUnitTestCase** should fix the problem.

```
class HomeControllerTests extends grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase {
    ....
}
```

The various ways of generating a test class all seem to vary the class that is extended.

```
create-integration-test => GroovyTestCase
create-unit-test => GrailsUnitTestCase
create-controller => ControllerUnitTestCase
```

However, according to the [Test section of the Grails User Guide](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/9.%20Testing.html), **GrailsUnitTestCase** is the core part of the testing frame and, at least in 1.3.7, that is the best class to base test classes on.